# How to unzip and download all images from zip folder using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried using jszip and able to extract only 10 images from the zip file.But ZIp file contains 450 images.

By using the below code I am able to download 10 images only. Not extracting all images of zip folder.

```
function unzipfeb146() {
var i = 0;
// fetch('file:///C:/CBTOffline/Images/8687.Zip')
fetch('http://localIP/CBT/R3Images/QBQuestionImages/8688.zip')
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(data => {
        // Extract the files from the zip
        const zip = new JSZip();
        return zip.loadAsync(data);
    })
    .then(zip => {
        // Download each file
        Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(filename => {
            debugger;
            zip.files[filename].async('blob').then(blob => {
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                `your text`
                link.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();


                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.id = i + 1;
                document.body.appendChild(img);
                i = i + 1;
                //const image = new Image();
                //image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                //image.id = fileName;
                //document.body.appendChild(image);

                //document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Expected out put as below :

[image]

Comment: Blind suggestion – maybe the problem is filesize? 450 images sounds like enough data to make problems. Check if it's going to work if file is really, really small.

Comment: Little suggestion, instead of `i = i + 1;` you can type `i++;` and it will do the same. Also, you could use it before the `img.id = i + 1;` and then just type `img.id = i;` instead.

Answer (score -1):

To create a download link for a zipped file, you can use the  tag with the href attribute pointing to the location of the zipped file, like this:

Download file

Comment: "To create a download link for a zipped file" — That isn't what they are asking for.